# How to Save files to system files on Android

Tags: android, file-copying

I want to save file to  files system on Android to this path "/efs/wifi/"
I created My file by FileWriter writer =new FileWriter (file,true) i want save this file to path above 
For root devices 
Another thing how can i copy from sd card to same path above "efs/wifi/"  Please help me .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a look at the link to review how to ask a good question. This will help others understand what you're looking for and provide a great answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libsupersu](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser) to make application for root device.

Add dependency to your gradle file:

```
compile 'eu.chainfire:libsuperuser:1.0.0.+'
```

In your code, ask root permission by:

```
Shell.SU.available();
```

After your app grant permission from user, you can copy file to anywhere to want.

Comment: Please write the code who will save my file to files system wirhout problems . Thanx for answer 